# Eliminar y actualizar un modelo relacionado en php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

he estado trabajando en una app web tipo encuesta por medio de estapas - preguntas - respuestas, ahora mismo ya tengo la parte de guardar las respuestas de cada pregunta y las preguntas en su respectiva etapa, pero en el momento de actualizar o eliminar una etapa, queda actualizada con la ultima informacion, pero por ejemplo si elimine un pregunta, no aparece visualmente, pero en la base de datos queda la pregunta con sus respuestas ocupando espacio

> Describo en img cual es el problema

[image: Imagen 1]

Tengo 2 preguntas en la etapa, como se puede ver, si elimino una, tendria que quedarme como muestro en la **Imagen de abajo**, pero no es asi, siempre me muestra las misma, si agrego obviamente si me lo agrega, no se como eliminar esa relacion en la base de datos para que se actualize

[image: imagen2]

> EstapasEdit.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('content')

    <form action="/dashboard/formulario/stages/{{ $stage->id }}" method="post">
        @method('put')
        <h2>ETAPA</h2>
        <label>Titulo</label>
        <input required type="text" name="title" value="{{ $stage->title }}">
        <label>Descripcion</label>
        <input required type="text" name="description" value="{{ $stage->description }}">

        <h2>PREGUNTAS</h2>
        <table>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($questions as $question)
                <tr>
                    <td><input required name="questions[{{ $question->id }}]" type="text" value="{{ $question->title }}" ><td/>
                    <td>
                        <select name="types[{{ $question->id }}]" id="">
                            @foreach($types as $type)
                                @if($type->name == $question->type->name)
                                    <option selected value="{{ $type->id }}">{{ @strtoupper($type->name) }}</option>
                                @else
                                    <option value="{{ $type->id }}">{{ @strtoupper($type->name) }}</option>
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Respuestas</legend>
                            @foreach($question->answers as $answer)

                                    @if($question->type->name == App\Type::OPCIONES['U'])
                                        <input required name="answers[{{ $question->id }}][{{ $answer->id }}]" type="text" value="{{ $answer->title }}">

                                    @elseif($question->type->name == App\Type::OPCIONES['C'])
                                        <input required name="answers[{{ $question->id }}][{{ $answer->id }}]" type="text" value="{{ $answer->title }}">

                                    @elseif($question->type->name == App\Type::OPCIONES['M'])
                                        <input required name="answers[{{ $question->id }}][{{ $answer->id }}]" type="text" value="{{ $answer->title }}">

                                    @endif

                            @endforeach
                        </fieldset>
                                <a href="">Agregar</a>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Guardar">
    </form>

@endsection
```

> Modelo Etapa

```
class Stage extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'title',
        'description'
    ];

    public function questions(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Question');
    }

}
```

> Modelo Pregunta

```
class Question extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'questions';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'title',
        'stage_id',
        'type_id',
    ];

    public function stage() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Stage');
    }

    public function type(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Type');
    }

    public function answers(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Answer');
    }

}
```

> Modelo Respuesta

```
class Answer extends Model
{

    public function __construct(array $attributes = ['title'])
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }

    protected $table = 'answers';
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'question_id'
    ];

    public function question() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Question');
    }

    public static function create(array $array) {
        $answers = [];


        return $answers;
    }

}
```

> Parte del controlador que actualiza

```
public function update(Request $request, Stage $stage)
{

    $rules = [
        'title' => 'max:150|string|unique:stages',
        'description' => 'max:250|string'
    ];

    $stage = Stage::findOrFail($stage)->first();

    if ($request->get('title') != $stage->title ||
        $request->get('description') != $stage->description) {

        $this->validate($request, $rules);
        $stage->title = $request->get('title');
        $stage->description = $request->get('description');

        $stage->save();
    }

    /*--------- SE RECORRE TODAS LAS PREGUNTAS  ---------*/
    foreach ($request->get('questions') as $id_q => $question) {
        $question_test = new Question([
            'id' => $id_q,
            'title' => $question
        ]);
        $type = Type::findOrFail($request->get('types')[$id_q]);

        /*--------- SE ACTUALIZA LOS DATOS DE LA PREGUNTA ---------*/
        $question_test->stage()->associate($stage);
        $question_test->type()->associate($type);

        if ($question_test->title == '') {
            /*TODO: AGREGAR ENVIO DE ERROR*/
        }

        $question_test = Question::updateOrCreate([
            'id' => $question_test->id
        ],[
            'title' => $question_test->title,
            'stage_id' => $question_test->stage_id,
            'type_id' => $question_test->type_id
        ]);

        /*--------- SE ACTUALIZA LOS RESPUESTAS DE LA PREGUNTA ---------*/
        foreach ($request->get('answers') as $key => $answers) {
            if ($id_q == $key) {
                foreach ($answers as $id_a => $answer) {

                    if ($answer == '') {
                        /*TODO: AGREGAR ENVIO DE ERROR*/
                    }

                    $question_test->answers()->updateOrCreate([
                        'id' => $id_a
                    ],[
                        'title' => $answer
                    ]);

                }
            }
        }

    }

    return redirect('/dashboard/formulario/stages');

}
```

> Migraciones
>
> Etapas

```
class CreateStagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('stages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('stages');
    }
}
```

> Preguntas

```
class CreateQuestionsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->unsignedInteger('stage_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('type_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('stage_id')->references('id')->on('stages');
            $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('types');
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('questions_type_id_foreign');
            $table->dropForeign('questions_stage_id_foreign');
        });
        Schema::dropIfExists('questions');
    }
}
```

> Respuestas

```
class CreateAnswersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->unsignedInteger('question_id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions');
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('answers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign('answers_question_id_foreign');
        });
        Schema::dropIfExists('answers');
    }
}
```

Comment: Tendría que ver los FOREIGN KEY de las tablas relacionadas con las preguntas, a primera vista tal vez no esta ON DELETE CASCADE para que se eliminen las relaciones sin se elimina a la tabla con el FOREIGN KEY.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Comment: es una buena solucion, no habia pensado en el on delete cascade, pero el problema que tengo ahora es que no se como saber cual es la que voy a eliminar, porque ya no mandaria datos de ese modelo, entonces no sabria cual es para hacerle el delete

Comment: En principio deberías eliminar todas las relaciones si eliminas la respuesta en si, porque sus relaciones no serian útil, si tienes una tabla para almacenar las relaciones de preguntas -> respuestas, su función termina a la hora de eliminar la pregunta.

Comment: No es la mas refinada solución, pero eliminar todo y luego grabar lo que ya tienes en el formulario podría funcionar (al menos hasta que si encuentres una solución más digna). Mal que mal, ya tienes la lógica creada y funcional para nuevas preguntas...

Comment: A ver si estoy entendiendo bien: El botón `eliminar` elimina una pregunta? Pero lo hace mediante `JavaScript` y solo la remueve visualmente, es decir, no envía ninguna consulta al backend, es así? Tu problema es que el *eliminar* la pregunta desde el formulario NO la elimina de la base de datos? Confirmá eso y publicá los archivos de migraciones o la estructura de la DB por lo que te preguntaron de las claves foráneas.

Comment: SI, el boton eliminar solo la elimina visualmente, la idea es que cuando le de guardar, solo se guarden o se actualicen las que queda, estare agregando las migraciones.

Comment: Añade en tu archivo de migración de la tabla que es padre de las demas la que tiene la relacion con todas las restantes, despues del ->on('tablaNombre')->onDelete('cascade'); Para que cuando elimines esa se eliminen las que estan relacionadas con ellas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El «problema» radica en que Laravel no tiene una forma (sencilla) de sincronizar relaciones uno-a-muchos, como sí lo incluye para relaciones muchos-a-muchos, y funciona de maravilla.

Aquí puedes acudir a varias soluciones:

- Hacer tu propia implementación en el o los modelos para sincronizar los elementos que deben estar o no en la relación (puede ser un poco extenso).
- Eliminar todas las preguntas cada vez que envías los datos de «actualización» y crear las preguntas de nuevo (NO recomendado por las consecuencias que puede acarrear el borrado de las llaves foráneas).
- Hacer lo contrario a la solución anterior (primero actualizar y luego borrar las que no necesitas).

---

Por simplicidad, voy a exponer la última solución que planteo, es algo más bien rudimentario, pero te permite entender el concepto en caso que desees una implementación más profesional desde el modelo o agregando tu servicio/paquete.

Voy a mostrar únicamente las partes del método del controlador que necesito.

```
public function update(Request $request, Stage $stage)
{
    // ...

    $questionsToKeep = [];

    foreach ($request->get('questions') as $id_q => $question) {


        // NO ESTOY SEGURO de entender por qué haces esto...
        $question_test = new Question([
            'id' => $id_q,
            'title' => $question
        ]);

        // ...

        // La pregunta se actualiza si existe, o se crea si no
        $question_test = Question::updateOrCreate([
            'id' => $question_test->id
        ],[
            'title' => $question_test->title,
            'stage_id' => $question_test->stage_id,
            'type_id' => $question_test->type_id
        ]);


        // almacenanos el id de la pregunta que recién creamos/actualizamos
        $questionsToKeep[] = $question_test->id;

        // ...

    }

    // Una vez hayamos procesado las preguntas y respuestas que enviamos,
    // obtenemos todas las preguntas almacenadas, comparamos
    // y eliminamos aquellas que no estén en el array de "mantener"

    $allQuestions = $stage->load('questions')->questions;

    $allQuestions->each(function ($item, $key) use ($questionsToKeep) {

        // iteramos la colección de preguntas para esta etapa,
        // si el id de la pregunta no fue almacenado antes,
        // no lo necesitamos, entonces borramos esa pregunta.
        if (! in_array($item->id, $questionsToKeep)) {
            $item->delete();
        }

    });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, al parecer si tenia pensado implementar un metodo, porque viendo mucho no encontraba nada acerca de ello en la documentacion. pero no habia pensado claro en eliminar las que ya no llamaba. Buenas respuesta

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que tenés un array (`$questionsToKeep`) que contiene los IDs que NO querés borrar, en vez de traer todas las preguntas, no podrías traer directamente las que querés borrar? Algo así se me ocurre: `$stage->questions()->whereNotIn('id', $questionsToKeep)->get()`.